# What setups are necessary to run Cucumber with tags in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I am using Cucumber plugin to run feature file in Eclipse. I am trying to use tags to select which scenarios I'd like to run.

In my feature file, I tag two scenarios with different tags as below:

```
Feature: Test

  @one
  Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
    Given User is on Home Page
    When User Navigate to LogIn Page
    And User enters UserName 123 and Password "def"
    Then Message displayed Login Successfully

  @two
  Scenario: Test Number And String Argument
    Given a $100 microwave was sold on "2015-11-03"
    And today is "2015-11-18"
```

In my Junit test runner file, I am using standard implementation:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Feature"
        ,glue={"stepDefinition"}
        ,tags={"@one"}
        )

public class CucumberJunitTest {
}
```

However, when i run the Junit runner, it just run **ALL** scenarios in feature file instead of ONLY running the @one scenario.

What did I do wrong? Am I missing some configurations in Eclipse?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, but without the curly brackets:

```
 ,tags="@one"
```

Comment: @cucumber-jvm takes 'string[]' as argument for tags, so adding curly bracket is not the problem. Maybe it's my system setup.

Comment: I cannot find any special configuration for cucumber.